# Проблема с wow.js (ошибка config)

Tags: javascript, wow.js

Поставил wow.js.
Анимация срабатывает, но по ее окончанию выпадает ошибка в консоль. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

инициализация:

```
$(function () {
wow = new WOW({
 boxClass:     'wow',
 animateClass: 'animated',
 offset:       0,
 mobile:       true,
 live:         true,
 scrollContainer: null,
 resetAnimation: true,
 })
 wow.init();
})
```

Брал wow.js и animate.css с гитхаба.